# how to make index at foreach and make it as json?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I want to save my data from foreach as "name data": value to variable ChartVal, but I don't how to do it I'm still learning.

```
  <?php 
        $nim = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $chart = $this->modelpenilaian->getchart($nim);
        foreach ($chart as $ca) {
            $a[i] = "$ca->name": $ca->nilai;
        } //I know this is wrong, I just don't know the right one



    ?>
    <script>
       var chartVals = <?php echo json_encode($a[i])?>;
    //I want to save to variable chartVals

    $(function(){
      $('#chart').radarChart({
        size: [500, 400],
        step: 1,
        title: " ",
        values: {
          //"chartVals": chartVals
          //then send it to jquery value
          chartVals
        },
        showAxisLabels: true
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely need to set the key of `$a` array to the name you want (`$ca->name` in your case)....

```
    $a=array();
    foreach ($chart as $ca) {
        $a[$ca->name] = $ca->nilai;
    }
```

and then

```
echo json_encode($a);
```

When adding the data to the chart, you need to use

```
values: chartVals,
```

Comment: hello, thanks this what i'm looking for but my chart still doesn't show can you help me ... <script>
   var chartVals = {"Bahasa":"5"}; << the result


$(function(){
  $('#chart').radarChart({
    size: [500, 400],
    step: 1,
    title: " ",
    values: {
      chartVals << I don't know why this is doesn't work
     
    },
    showAxisLabels: true
  });
});

Comment: So what should I do my friend ?

Comment: from my database $chart = $this->modelpenilaian->getchart($nim);

Comment: public function getchart($nim){
  $sql = $this->db->query("select a.nama_pelajaran, b.nilai, c.nim from nilaidetail b join pelajaran a on a.id_pelajaran = b.id_pelajaran join nilai c on c.id_nilai = b.id_nilai where c.nim = '$nim'");

  return $sql->result();
 }

Comment: hi, thanks for your help. I don't know your suggest doesn't wrong because the result var chartVals = {"Agama":5,"Penjas":5,"Sosial":5,"Bahasa":5,"Seni":5}; and this is right ... but whenever I trying to put variable chartVals as value the chart doesn't show up... but when I copy variable chartVals manually to the value then it's work  values: {
     "Agama":5,"Penjas":5,"Sosial":5,"Bahasa":5,"Seni":5
     
    },
but when I call chartVals it's doesn't work values: {
     chartVals
     
    },

Comment: Can you make sure it is the same, try `values: chartVals,` (without the {})

Comment: OMG, my bad, thanks you so much I almost get frustrated. youre so kind :')

Comment: It's difficult sometimes as you make changes and things get closer but don't always work.  As long as it is sorted that's the main thing.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
foreach ($chart as $ca) {
    $a[$ca->name] = $ca->nilai;
}
```

That gives you an array of key:value pairs. To turn it into JSON you would:

```
$myJSON = json_encode($a);
```